# Flask-Login shows 401 instead of redirecting to login view

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Using Flask-Login, I want to require login for some views.  When I try to access a view that is decorated with `@login_required`, I get a 401 message instead of the login page.  How do I set this up correctly?

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required, login_user

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # authenticate user from form
        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/protected')
@login_required
def protected():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Answer (score 13):

You haven't told Flask-Login what view to use to show the login form, so it defaults to a generic 401 error.  From the [docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#customizing-the-login-process): "If the login view is not set, it will abort with a 401 error."

```
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
```